# What will be assigned into pointer pfile?

Tags: c

```
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","r");
if (pFile == NULL)
{ some code }

pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","r")
```

in this case what will be assigned to `pFile`? since `pFile` is a pointer which only stores address of another variable. I wonder "myfile.txt" is a string right? So is it that 
pFile = address of array which store the string "myfile.txt" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It points to a `FILE` object.  The details are implementation-dependent, and don't affect user code.  But it will typically be a structure that includes various references to OS-specific file-handling mechanisms.

This is an example of an [*opaque pointer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

If the file is successfully opened, the function returns a pointer to a FILE object that can be used to identify the stream on future operations.
Otherwise, a null pointer is returned.

Answer (score 0):

It is a pointer to a `FILE` structure, which includes all the information that the OS needs to access files on your behalf.

You shouldn't use `fopen` in C++; you should use a `std::ifstream` instead.

Comment: "Shouldn't" is a strong word.  There are plenty of cases where the old C-style `fprintf`-style API is just easier to use than C++ streams.  (Google, for example, forbids streams in their [style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Streams)).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yep; deliberate. You should never use `fprintf` in C++.

Comment: That's an opinion, sure.  But plenty would disagree with you ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Why would you want to use the insecure, non-typesafe, slow version?

Comment: Well, check out the link in my previous comment for some reasons.  But it's also just easier and cleaner to express formatted output with `printf` in many circumstances.  Having to write all this `std::setprecision(X) << std::setw(Y)` nonsense all over the place makes code look horrible.  And it's not necessarily slow, either.  On the other hand, the ability to overload `<<` for arbitrary types is a definite win for streams (although again, see the comments in the Google style guide on that notion...)

Answer (score 0):

From the fopen man page:

```
SYNOPSIS
       #include <stdio.h>

       FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);

       FILE *fdopen(int fd, const char *mode);

       FILE *freopen(const char *path, const char *mode, FILE *stream);

   Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

       fdopen(): _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE

DESCRIPTION
       The fopen() function opens the file whose name is the string pointed to by path and associates a stream with it.
```

So the pointer returned is used to access the stream to the file.